# App Engine PHP upload file

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm trying to figure out how to upload my files correctly to Google App Engine. Everything works if I declare a handler for a static directory named images - there's no upload statement needed - but if I try to use regex to upload only web graphics, the files (evidently) aren't uploaded.

Here's my app.yaml:

```
application: static-files-demo-999
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles

- url: /images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/images/\1
  upload: images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /.*
  script: main.php
```

As far as I can tell, it's exactly like the docs say, just targeting my images folder. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

Best - Joe

Comment: Do you get any errors or have access to any logs? Do you have a link to the original example?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346622/google-app-engine-php-app-images-css-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I was following the documentation too literally and including the static folder in my path. Here's the correct code:

```
- url: /images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: images/\1
  upload: images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```

Hopefully this will stop others from making the same (bonehead) mistake.

- Joe