# image upload to google bucket ay cloud storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I was testing the following piece of code, to see If I can upload images to the bucket at google's cloud storage.

This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: test-795  
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.php).*
  script: \1  

- url: /upload
  script: fileimage.php
```

and this is my fileimage.php file for uploading image file to bucket:

```
<?php

 require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
 use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

 $options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'test-795.appspot.com' ];
 $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload', $options);

   if(isset($_POST['do-upload']) AND $_POST['do-upload'] === "yes"){

   $yesupload = $_POST['do-upload'];
   preg_match("/yes/", "".$yesupload."");

   $filename = $_FILES['testupload']['name'];

   $gs_name = $_FILES['testupload']['tmp_name'];
   move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://test-795.appspot.com/'.$filename.'');
?>

<div class="contentArea">
<?php
echo "<p class=\"SomeSpaceDude\">Hey file is uploaded, Yes! ".$yesupload." !</p>";
echo "<p class=\"SomeSpaceDude\">This is the file name: ".$filename."</p>";
}

echo"</div>";
?>

<form class="SomeSpaceDude" action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>Files to upload: </p> <br>
 <input type="hidden" name="do-upload" value="yes">
 <input class="SomeSpaceDude topcoat-button" type="file" name="testupload" >
 <input class="SomeSpaceDude topcoat-button" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</div>
```

when I run the file using localhost:8080 i get the message **Hey file is uploaded, Yes! yes !** My web address becoming like : localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ahVkZXZ-Y... 
Checking on my bucket at google storage which has the name test-795 and nothing is uploaded.

I have also deploy it, and when I test it after pressing upload button, I get an empty page and web address link looks like: test-795.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6... Checking at my bucket nothing inside again ofcourse. 
Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running in the development server the file does not get uploaded to the real Cloud Storage service, only a local emulation.

On the production server, check the logs to see what might be happening with your upload.

Comment: I am trying to work with GCS locally as well. Is there a way to view the emulated bucket? And why would my uploads fail locally, when they work 100% when deployed?

Answer (score 1):

The bove code works fine...I found finally that the problem was, that I should use everywhere in the above code test-795, instead of test-795.appspot.com